# How to exit Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

In Stack Overflow, how do I exit the site? If I click "delete" from the user home page my account is deleted. I can't find "sign out". Please tell me.

(I am not leave,just clear cookie,but I can't find "sign out",so I think "Delete" is "sign out",so I have a try but my account is deleted.)

Comment: why you want to leave? IS stackoverflow not helpfull to you

Comment: To be fair, this is a bit buried in the UI now! Could we not have a little icon in the header?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0G1Ucw5HDg

Comment: We don't want you to leave. You are supposed to stay here... forever!

Comment: We all float down here, Henry! We all float! When you're down here with us, you'll float too!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go, click on the menu bar:

[image]

P.S.: Although I answer this, on the opposite, you are supposed to stay here... forever! I rather regard it well designed in this way to keep you always alive once born. :P

Comment: great answer.. motivate him to stay here ;)

Comment: That won't really log him out of the website. Follow the step above and click 'Log Out' button again @LiuBinqiang. :P

Answer (score 1):

> [image]

Follow [herohuyongtao's step](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223177/152859) and click on 'Log Out' button as shown above.

But remember. That is your last chance and there is NO turning back.

You take the blue Log Out pill. The story ends, you shake uncontrollably with deep fear and regret wondering what you've just done.

You take the red cancel pill. You stay in Stack Overflow wonderland and I show you how addictive Stack Overflow can be.

Remember all I am offering is the truth - Nothing more.

Comment: -1. The "Log Out" button in your answer doesn't work.